# xdocument adding xdocument

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces

I am doing something wrong can't grab shipmentreceiptlineitem to add to first document, do I need to add a namespace?

```
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("FirstPart.xml");
        xdoc.Root.Add(XDocument.Load("RepeatingPart.xml").Element("ShipmentReceiptLineItem").Elements());
```

xml to grab from:

```
 <tns:ShipmentReceiptNotification xmlns:dl="urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Logistics:xsd:schema:02.18"
 xmlns:tns="urn:rosettanet:specification:interchange:ShipmentReceiptNotification:xsd:schema:02.01">
<tns:ShipmentReceiptLineItem>
</tns:ShipmentReceiptLineItem>
</tns:ShipmentReceiptNotification>
```

Comment: You're loading two documents, but you've only shown one of them - and you haven't said what the result is compared with what you want it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to use the namespace when you try to find the `ShipmentReceiptLineItem` element. You *also* need to go from the root element, otherwise your check for `Element(...)` would only be able to *find* the root element:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("FirstPart.xml");
XNamespace tns = "urn:rosettanet:specification:interchange:ShipmentReceiptNotification:xsd:schema:02.01";
xdoc.Root.Add(XDocument.Load("RepeatingPart.xml")
                       .Root
                       .Element(tns + "ShipmentReceiptLineItem")
                       .Elements());
```

Or splitting it up further:

```
XDocument repeatingDoc = XDocument.Load("RepeatingPart.xml");
XNamespace tns = "urn:rosettanet:specification:interchange:ShipmentReceiptNotification:xsd:schema:02.01";    
var elementsToAdd = repeatingDoc.Root
                                .Element(tns + "ShipmentReceiptLineItem")
                                .Elements());
var mainDoc = XDocument.Load("FirstPart.xml");
mainDoc.Root.Add(elementsToAdd);
```

I find this a lot simpler to read than doing everything in one go. You could potentially get rid of the `repeatingDoc` variable and do *that* bit inline, but I definitely wouldn't do the *whole* thing inline.

Comment: minor changes to grabbing element based on my needs but it works great as a base.  thank u